# Do PDEs arise in the context of Varieties?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

My work involves designing numerical methods to solve PDEs on manifolds. This situation often arises in many applications in biology, chemistry, physics etc. I've recently been reading about Varieties, and how they are closely related to manifolds (with the main difference being that Varieties can have singular points). This leads me to ask the following questions:

1. Is there a notion of solving PDEs on Varieties, similar to the notion of solving PDEs on manifolds?
2. Is question 1 even a meaningful question to ask for Varieties in general? For example, are there only specific types/classes of Varieties on which it makes sense to talk about PDEs?

If this notion exists, could you also provide examples (or links to examples) of a few places where such PDEs arise?

Note: I've capitalized the first letter of Varieties for clarity.

Comment: You can try Googling "D-modules". To be honest, though, I have no idea how much work has been done on D-modules on singular varieties.

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh Cool, thank you. This is at least a partial answer to my question (sans examples). Care to write it as an answer so I can upvote?